# Distorted elementary functions

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, special-functions

Let $f(x)$ be an elementary function defined on $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\xi(x), \eta(y)$ strictly monotone for $x\in X,\, y\in f(x)$.

**Questions:**

- is there an established name for functions of the form $\eta(f(\xi(x)))$, e.g. if $f(x)$ is a polynomial?
- are there classes of functions, say polynomials, that can be recognized from a distorted definition, resp., when is it possible to recover $f(x)$ from $\eta(f(\xi(x)))$ if the type (e.g. polynomial) of $f(x)$ is known?

Comment: When you say “recover”, do you imply whether we can find (other strictly monotonic functions) $\eta’$ and $\xi’$ such that $f=\eta’\circ g\circ \xi’$ when $g= \eta\circ f\circ \xi$?

Comment: @JackL. Yes, that is what I am looking for; essentially a way of constrained denesting of functions. Maybe the functional analysis tag would also fit the question.

Comment: Well in that case, strict monotonicity of $\eta$ and $\xi$ guarantees injectivity and, therefore, invertibility on their respective images; so barring countable sets of jump discontinuities—thanks to Darboux-Froda—we should have that $\eta^{-1}\circ g\circ \xi^{-}$ should recover all $f$ when $g=\eta\circ f\circ \xi$; in particular, the restriction to the case of invertible $\eta$ and $\xi$ suffices, not so?

Comment: @Jack ... so maybe the question is: Given a function $\phi(x)$, can we determine whether it is of the form $\phi(x) = \eta(f(\xi(x)))$ with $f$ a polynomial and $\xi, \eta$ strictly monotone?

Comment: @JackL. the monotonicity restrictions on $\xi()$ and $\eta()$ have been made exactly to guarantee that knowing the two allows for recovering $f()$ but knowing *that it can be done* is only half the rent; the other half would be *knowing how to do it* if the two are unknown and the only information we have about $f()$ were that it is polynomial. An idea might be to look at the Taylor series because sufficiently high derivatives of polynomials vanish.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar & Manfred Weis: That’s well understood. Thanks.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t recover more information about $f$ than basic shape (how many local extrema it has, and whether it is increasing or decreasing between them). For example, if $f_0$ and $f_1$ are monotone polynomials, there are continuous monotone functions $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that $\eta\circ f_0\circ\xi=f_1$, hence you can’t distinguish distorted $f_0$ from distorted $f_1$.